# Weird Math: Said Grandpa

Tags: knowledge, lateral-thinking

"You think my math can sometimes be crazy? Just look at this equation I received from my cousin! Very Weird", said Grandpa.

[image]

"We are going to need some creative thinking to prove this one. And then he says that using similar logic you can equate those numbers to one more two digit number."

Can you prove it? And what is the additional number?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

2222

> V is the 22nd letter in the alphabet → **VV**

23

> W is the 23rd letter in the alphabet → **W**

2323

> 23 is the atomic number of Vanadium  → **VV**

And the additional number is

> **74** as it's the atomic number of Tungsten → **W**

Comment: You could also make an argument for 42, because it is the answer for everything, but perhaps more relevantly, it is rot13(qbhoyr H). And then you could get 184 in the mix too!

Comment: Yes, 2121 (nice writing this as 42) works when spoken which would also give 9292 (184).

Comment: Naq I vf nyfb 5 va ebzna ahzrenyf. Fb 55 nyfb. V ery W eird.